# how to write linq query with where clause to get records between 9 am to 5 pm

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

how to write a linq query with  to get records between 9 am 5 pm only. the records beyond that should be discarded.

timestamp datatype

[image]

code

```
var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA=") && (fromDate == null || fromDate.Value.Date <= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && (toDate == null || toDate.Value.Date >= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date))
                     .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
                     .Select(g => g.First()).OrderBy(a => a.timestamp);
```

Comment: What is `fromDate` in your LINQ query ?? Maybe if you can simplify it further somebody can help you.

Comment: im passing two dates from date and to date. with in these dates i need the records with in the time of 9am to 5pm only. data between the 9 am to 5 pm in the between selected dates.

Comment: so your `fromDate` and `toDate` is TimeSpan as well? Or is it `Date`

Comment: You want all the dates between two dates and between 9 am and 5 pm ??

Comment: data type - DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq filter by time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991481/linq-filter-by-time-range)

Answer (score 5):

```
Pirs.Where(a.timestamp.TimeOfDay > new TimeStamp(9, 0, 0) &&   //all times after 9am
           a.timestamp.TimeOfDay < new TimeStamp(17, 0, 0) &&  //all times before 5pm
           a.timestamp.Date > fromDate &&                      //all dates after fromData
           a.timestamp.Date < toDate)                          //all dates before toDate
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the following in where condition

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("09:00:00");
TimeSpan espan = TimeSpan.Parse("17:00:00");

Pirs.Where(a => a.timestamp >= startDate && a.timestamp <= toDate && a.timestamp.TimeOfDay >= span && a.timestamp.TimeOfDay <= espan);
```